# Is this proof that $0\cdot{\bar{v}} = \textbf{0}$, for any vector $\bar{v} \in V$ incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I know a proof of this fact, but I am more interested logically in what is happening in the following argument:

**Proof**

To prove the statement, we must prove $\forall \bar{v} \in V \forall \bar{h} \in V \big(0\cdot\bar{v} + \bar{h} = \bar{h}\big)$. Suppose $\bar{v}$, $\bar{h}$, are arbitrary vectors. Consider $$ \begin{align} 0 \cdot \bar{v} + \bar{h} & = 0 \cdot \bar{v}+ 1 \cdot \bar{h} \\ & = 0 \cdot \bar{v} + (1+0) \cdot \bar{h} \\ & = 0 \cdot \bar{v} + 0 \cdot \bar{h} + 1 \cdot \bar{h} \end{align} $$

Let $\bar{a} = 0 \cdot \bar{v} + \bar{h}$. Then we have $\bar{a} = \bar{a} + 0 \cdot \bar{h}$.

At this point I was tempted to say that the proof is complete, since $\bar{h}$ is arbitrary, and it is the zero vector. But I think this logic is wrong? Am I correct now in saying that it is wrong because (i) the statement $\forall \bar{v} \in V \forall \bar{h} \in V \big(0\cdot\bar{v} + \bar{h} = \bar{h}\big)$ remains unproven, and (ii) that the vector $\bar{a}$ is not necessarily arbitrary, since it is dependent on the vector addition of $0 \cdot \bar{v}$ and $\bar{h}$?

I'm a bit confused by the logic here, since I am not sure that we can really conclude $\bar{a}$ is arbitrary? (I know that since it is actually true that $0 \cdot \bar{v}$ is the zero vector, then $\bar{a}$ is arbitrary because $\bar{h}$ is arbitrary, but that seems circular since I haven't yet proved the result in this case)

I am also wondering that if there is indeed some way to show that $\bar{a}$ is arbitrary, does that mean the proof is complete? My reasoning here being that we have proven the initial statement $\forall \bar{v} \in V \forall \bar{h} \in V \big(0\cdot\bar{v} + \bar{h} = \bar{h}\big)$, just that we have replaced $\bar{v}$ by $\bar{h}$, and $\bar{h}$ by $\bar{a}$. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rewrite what you did:

1. choose $v,h$ arbitrarily
2. then for some $a=a(h,v)$ we have $a=a+0\cdot h$
3. using the properties of addition, it follows that $0=0\cdot h$
4. $h$ was arbitrary, hence we proved $\forall h\quad 0\cdot h =0$

You didn't prove $\forall \bar{v} \in V \forall \bar{h} \in V \big(0\cdot\bar{v} + \bar{h} = \bar{h}\big)$, neither you used it to prove $\forall h\quad 0\cdot h =0$.

---

$a$ is not arbitrary, since it depends on $h,v$, but you can choose $h,v$ to make $a$ whatever you want. Indeed, every $a \in V$ can be written as $0\cdot v + h$ for some $v,h \in V$. Choose any $v \in V$, define $v':=0\cdot v$, and $h=a-v'$. Then $0\cdot v+h=v'+h=v'+a-v'=a$.

Comment: Ah OK thank you! I suppose the argument works if I prove that $\bar{a}$ is also arbitrary!